# WPF blocking InputBindings for shortcut when the focus is on TextBox kind of element

Tags: wpf, textbox, focus, tabcontrol, shortcut

I need tabs in TabControl navigated using Ctrl + PageUp/PageDown - previous/next. Everything works fine, until there is a TextBox control inside of a Tab and there is a focus on it. Then the shortcut won't work. Other key combos work fine, but PageUp and PageDown don't.
This is my Tab control:

```
 <TabControl.InputBindings>
  <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control"
              Key="PageDown"
              Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource ShortCutCommands}, Path=TabControlNextItemCommand}"
              CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TabControl}"/>
  <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control"
              Key="PageUp"
              Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource ShortCutCommands}, Path=TabControlPreviousItemCommand}"
              CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TabControl}"/>
</TabControl.InputBindings>
```

Did someone have a similar problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know using commands would be ideal, but if `TextBox` is eating those key inputs before the `KeyBinding` has a chance to work, the only solution I know of is to use the [`PreviewKeyDown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.previewkeydown) event instead of input bindings.

```
private void TabControl_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Tab && Keyboard.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Control))
    {
        //Invoke command here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
I did a bit other thing, I added a behavior for the TabControl which reads the button combination, and if it matches it fires the shortcut not the embedded command.
So, it is the same philosophy! :)